# How to Correctly Update Android UI from SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, multithreading

So I have an activity with a TextView to hold the score like so:

```
public class PlayGameActivity extends Activity {
    private GameThread mGameThread;
    private GameView mGameView;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);

        final TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        mGameView = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.gameView1);
        mGameThread = mGameView.getThread();

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mGameView != null) {
                    scoreView.setText(mGameThread.getScore());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then in my GameView I have the function declared like so:

```
class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    class GameThread extends Thread {
        int score = 0;

        public String getScore(){
            return Integer.toString(score);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                if (something){
                    score++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that mGameThread.getScore() always returns 0 as if score is not updated when it certainly is.

If anyone has any incite it is greatly appreciated. Also I have striped lots of unnecessary code out of the snippets above. If you want to see the full text you may do so here:

- [PlayGameActivity.java](http://snipt.org/vXfg2)
- [GameView.java](http://snipt.org/vXfh3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a better way to update UI data, use event / listener mechanism.

Sitting in a looped thread is not an OOP style programming. If the change of score happens in your app than you definitely have a handle to detect the change. Once detected, update the UI with one simple setText call to your textview.

Do not overcrowd your UI event queue stack as you (maybe unknowingly) do by calling post(....), this will make your UI less responsive to actual user interactions especially if you're doing it in a timed loop. Remember that the UI event queue stack is ONE for the entire system, it is meant to handle user's interactions with the device.

If you need to change UI component from non-UI thread use

```
     activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable);
```

method instead of post(Runnable). This way you may have a bit longer executing code (although not recommended) defined in Runnable. Otherwise make sure that the code in post(Runnable) is very quick to execute and finish.

Comment: In a game you sometimes need to "sit in a looped thread". Gamelogic or drawing threads might enforce this. For a normal app the event/listener pattern is highly recommended.

Comment: The logic should be - if you can detect, or can **engineer** to detect the change then don't use waiting loops. That's a bad practice. There's no need to repaint the fence with the same colour every day.

Comment: Using an event / listener seems like the correct way to tackle my problem in English but I am having trouble with the implementation. If you could provide more detail particular to my specific situation. In the mean time I will try to figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: In your GameView class add a private Activity property and define the getter and setter methods. In the PlayGameActivity add mGameView.setActivity(this); right after initiating the mGameView variable. Then in the GameView, right after score++ add activity.runOnUiThread(soreViewRunnable); where scoreViewRunnable updates the score view. That's it. No need for looped checks and handlers.

Comment: Great this works but is this considered bad since it breaks the MVC pattern and has lots of talking back and fourth? I feel like just this line smells bad:
`playGameActivity.runOnUiThread(playGameActivity.updateScoreRunnable);`

Comment: Well we have addressed one bad practice by eliminating waiter loop. You can improve on it by creating a Listener class, which will be notified of the change and decide the next step (which could be updating the UI or any other action). This way you'll have separated the view from the business logic, and will have implemented the event/listener paradigm properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your Handler runs only once `getScore()` so you will always just get the initial value. You should try to use `postDelayed()`.

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (mGameView != null) {
            scoreView.setText(mGameThread.getScore());
        }
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // run again in 1sec
    }
}, 1000);
```

As Thomas mentions that Handler should not be used in such a way here is a quote from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html):

> There are two main uses for a Handler: (1) to schedule messages and runnables to be executed as some point in the future; and (2) to enqueue an action to be performed on a different thread than your own.

It fits perfectly in (1)!

Comment: This isn't the way Handlers are meant to be used, as you're basically sending messages from the UI thread back into the UI thread. So I suggest that the Handler is used from GameThread.

Comment: @ThomasCalc An easy and efficient way for constant UI updates are handler. So this is a valid and often used solution for this use case.

Comment: I don't doubt that, but in this concrete case, when you're writing a value from another thread, the most elegant (and readable) place is to add it to the non-UI thread. It has reduced complexity with the same efficiency (and offers implicit synchronization, i.e. will work even if score wasn't between memory barriers). (The complexity is reduced because there is no need to add the additional delayed message sending. Moreover, sending delayed messages might not integrate well into future developments e.g. if you add a new message type -- think of serialization i.e. happens-before relationships.

Comment: Moreover, your solution will not be in sync with the actual value of the score, because it's basically a polling in every second. E.g. if the score gets increased 3 times per second (i.e. in every 333th millisecond -- noticeable for the human eye), my suggestion will update the UI after a few milliseconds (= time of message dispatching within the underlying Looper), while your solution even might miss some values (due to the 1000 ms delay).

Comment: I just read your edit: yes, it is good for future scheduling, but as I've written in the above comment, delayed scheduling is not the most elegant way to solve the current problem IMO.

Comment: @ThomasCalc I updated the answer with a quote from the documentation. Your posted solution has one big disadvantage: Messagespam! If the if statement is a lot of times true in a second your solution will result in message spam which will update the UI of a non-SurfaceView (probably mostly static) and therefore enforces a redraw which will drain the battery. The given delay is a sample. I wouldn't reduce it to less than 100 and there is nowhere mentioned, that the UI-Update has to be "realtime"...

Comment: To make it short and stop the "mine answer is better" silliness: I gave a `pull` solution, you the `push` solution. The OP can decide what he wants.

Comment: Yes, we can add a logical clock into it, I'll edit my post. It doesn't change on my point that an UI should be in sync with the game logic and game state. About the "silliness": I think it's a constructive conversation with rational arguments :)

Comment: I realized in the meantime that the OP's code must necessarily contain some sort of "logical clock" (measuring in-game time) or at least some real-time scheduling. Every game has such a thing. (If it's a turn-based game, then it's trivial.)

Comment: Still you switch from one argument to another as soon as the first one was proven invalid. I stop here because it is way beyond the OP and nobody cares. (And please stop spamming comments...) The "clock" is assuming based on not enough knowledge.... I don't repeat myself...

Comment: I'm writing VALID points, none were disproved. Your last comment was a pure spam indeed, as it had no computer science content (until you've just added the last sentence). Moreover, I don't switch arguments: all my arguments are still valid. (Which means that a properly designed game has an internal scheduler engine with time measuring mechanism, and keeps the UI sync with the logical state.) It's your problem if you can't accept that someone else provides a better solution than yourself. About "nobody cares": please read the stackoverflow FAQ about relevance and on-topicness.

Comment: There's a better way to update UI data, use events and listeners. Sitting in a looped thread is not an OOP style programming. If the change of score happens in your app than you definitely have a handle to detect the change. Once detected, update the UI with one simple setText call to your textview. Do not overcrowd your event queue stack  as you (maybe unknowingly) do by calling post(....), this will make your UI less responsive to actual user interactions.

Comment: @Nar Gar: the internal scheduling solution of the game makes it inherently event-based. The score is not incremented in an infinite loop for sure -- the player needs to do something to achieve it. Therefore, it happens in an event-based way.

Comment: @NarGar the postDelayed() solution is a pull solution which means a overcrowd event queue shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Well, the only difference is the first xxx milliseconds specified in postDelayed, from that point on the effect is exactly the same as you would've called plain post(...). Also it is a suitable solution when you don't have a handle to an activity only.

Comment: @NarGar could you explain that further?

Comment: @ThomasCalc Sorry but I can't resist: To your "ui in sync with game state" topic: You should check systems like "VSync". There you have a decoupling of UI from the game state. Depending on your game logic a "tick" might take longer that your UI needs to draw which might result in visual "effects" where the upper half of your screen shows an old state and the lower part the new state.

Comment: say you're calling postDelayed(Runnable, 100) in a loop each 100 milliseconds. What will happen is, the first call to Runnable will be scheduled and the loop will continue. The loop will wait for 100 mills to run another postDelayed. So after 100 mills the previous scheduled Runnable will run and a new one will be scheduled for 100 millis later. So the timing difference between post(Runnable) and postDelayed(Runnable, xxx) is just the initial xxx milliseconds of shift.

Comment: I didn't mean to update the UI in every tick(). I just said that in the OP's case, it is almost certain that the game has a logic which decides when to increment the player's score. Common sense says that this is time the update the UI as well. The big problem with your solution is that it doesn't care about game logic at all (i.e. it may happen that the score doesn't change for a minute, while at another time, it may change 4 times per sec). Therefore, this is more flood-prove for the message queue. My solution relies on the game logic -- and the game logic knows when it wants to update.

Comment: BTW, I agreed with the statement of WarrenFaith that this can be eventually summarized as a "push" vs. "pull" approach, and it will depend on the OP's final architecture which one he prefers. In this concrete case, my solution would be to implement proper FPS balancing and send a message whenever the score changes -- this is what I see to be a clean solution. But if the OP goes for a different architecture, then the approach of Nar Gar or WarrenFaith can fit too.

Comment: **I have tried this method and it does work.** However, I believe it is not the best for my situation because the update to the UI is based on a simple event. My implementation was aimed in the same direction as this answer so I understand the reason for the confusion. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1):

From where else do you call `mHandler.post(Runnable)`? The code you posted adds a single message (from your onCreate) to the message queue of the main thread, which does not make much sense. This message is processed, will print 0, and then that's it. So if you don't periodically call this from somewhere, it will not print anything after the initial 0.

If you're calling `Handler.post(Runnable)` from somewhere else as well, then make sure you call it from the correct place. It must be called from `GameThread` each time you want to update your UI. Therefore, you will need a reference to `mHandler` in GameThread. E.g. the constructor of `GameThread` is a good place to do this (I wouldn't implement `GameThread` as an inner class, but to each his own). Once `GameThread` has a reference to `mHandler`, you can use `mHandler.post(Runnable)` to update your UI. For example:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
            if (something){
                // IMPORTANT: see "important note" at the end of this Answer                          

                mHandler.post(mRunnable); // mRunnable is preinstantiated somewhere
                score++
            }
        }
    }
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: your `GameThread` probably uses a way to measure real time (i.e. it doesn't call everything in an infinite loop without any Thread.sleep(...). Therefore, "update score" messages to the `Handler` will not be sent excessively. If your game is turn based (and not realtime), then this problem even does not appear at all.

**NOTE 2:**: I checked your complete code, and it seems your game tick does not have any FPS regulation, i.e. you don't use e.g. `Thread.sleep(33)` or anything similar. Therefore, the solution I wrote above will send very many messages to your UI if your pirate collides (and your score will reach a very high value in a very short time -- **I doubt that is what you want**). In fact, your `score` value will probably overflow very soon, unless the collision ends very very fast. So I suggest that you add FPS balancing to your code, as all games do.

Comment: Wrong, it runs in a loop without `sleep()`.

Comment: It still needs to have a mechanism to schedule the game flow. For turn-based games, we wait for user input (to start the next turn). For scheduled (e.g. real-time) games with a main game loop, it must contain some sort of regulation mechanism (otherwise it's probably bad or incomplete design). EDIT: I checked the complete code the OP has linked to. Well, it is certainly not a good idea to update the game logic in an infinite loop (instead of using at least an internal logical clock), a waste of CPU.

Comment: Correction: "to update the game logic in an infinite loop **without any FPS balancing**"

Comment: With your update you are correct. Thanks for the attempt but it is event based so I do not think this is the best solution.

Comment: If it's event based, then all concrete implementations to update the UI will be very similar. (I don't see where it's event based, but I didn't have much time to view your code.) In other words, if it's event-based, then the solution will be pretty obvious, and there will be no risk to "overspam" the UI message queue.